# Error:Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.

[image: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.]

And in the console, it shows "UI component could not be rendered because of system exception" error.
after the change dropdown show, it error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the database and run this query below.

```
TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;
```

I think it will fix the filter problem and reset it but it's not a solution for the problem itself, if you add a filter that returns too many results, like 999 elements to the grid it will happen again.
That happened to me before, I think is something like a timeout I could only fix it by updating the Magento version.

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

If Rui's answer didn't solve by cleaning the database table with `TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;` you can try to increase the session limit.

[image: Magento 2 admin user session]

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem came from the **ui_bookmark** table feature of Magento 2 to store the admin user’s states. It always has a current & default state for each view in the Magento back-end we use. Let’s see how it is stored inside Magento Database for my own admin user with user_id = 1.

**For sales_order_grid**

You must be having trouble listing orders because their namespace is sales_order_grid.

```
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE namespace = 'sales_order_grid' AND identifier = 'current' AND user_id = '1'; /* your admin user
```

**For product_listing**

```
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE namespace = 'product_listing' AND identifier = 'current' AND user_id = 1
```

**For customer_listing**

```
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE namespace = 'customer_listing' AND identifier = 'current' AND user_id = 1
```

I found the solution here & thanks to [Magento2 Error Fix: “Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state”](https://www.codehref.com/magento2-error-fix-something-went-wrong-with-processing/)

In my case, I fixed it by increasing the session size,
*If the above method is not fixed, then check your debug.log (var/log/debug.log) file for what is the issue? Most of the time its error by session size exceed. So increase the admin session size. [Magento 2: How to set Admin Session Size – Easy Method](https://www.codehref.com/magento-2-how-to-set-admin-session-size-easy-method/)*

Comment: Thank you for your edit @RafaelCorrêaGomes

Answer (score 0):

If above solutions is not work out pls follow the bellow step.

Go to your directory: find the path mentioned bellow:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/ProductActions.php**

Change the Code From

```
‘ariaLabel’ => __(‘Edit ‘) . $item[‘name’],
```

To

```
‘ariaLabel’ => __(‘Edit ‘) . @$item[‘name’],
```

I found in [Magento 2.4+ Error:Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state](https://www.itcastlebd.com/errorsomething-went-wrong-with-processing-the-default-view-and-we-have-restored-the-filter-to-its-original-state/)  and its worked for me in Magento 2.4.5

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/207300)